# what is the use of "static_cast<void>" in macro?

Tags: c++, casting

I'm seeing a macro definition like this:

```
#define ASSERT_VALID_PARAM(param, assertion) {  static_cast<void>(param); if (!(assertion)) { throw InvalidParamError(#param, #assertion, __FILE__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__); } }
```

I'm not able to figure out the need of `static_cast<void>(param)` here.
Any idea on why this is needed?

Comment: This should help: [cppreference -- static_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast)

Comment: The macro should use `do` ... `while(0)`.

Comment: @jxh, The do.. while(0) is to handle the usage like "if(cond) MACRO" where MACRO has more than one line. But the additional curly braces in the MACRO definition should handle the same.

Comment: Except it doesn't. Without `do`.. `while(0)`, adding an `else` is an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This macro is designed to validate a certain *real* parameter passes a certain validation rule(s). The logic part of the macro is composed of 2 parts:

1. Validate that `param` is a real parameter, with a valid name. This is done by using the `static_cast`, and if an illegal name is used, a compile time error will be generated.
2. Validate the "truthyness" of `assertion`. This is done with a simple negating if statement.

If the param is a valid name, and the assertion fails (`assertion == false`), an `InvalidParamError` is thrown, using the passed in parameters as strings (using the [*Stringizing operator #*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7e3a913x.aspx)) to initialize the error object.

Since the actual usage of the `param` parameter in the macro is only as a string, it has to be validated using actual code. Since no real operation is needed the static_cast is used, which discards the result and can potentially be optimized out. Without that check, you could pass any value which would make the information in the assertion meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

it is the 'c++ way' of writing

```
(void)param;
```

it makes 'use' of the variable and thus disables the compiler warning for unused variable

Comment: And what is the `assertion` for? (the macro takes two arguments).

Comment: That's not the reason it's there. In fact, that's the unavoidable downside, where an otherwise unused variable might pass without warnings.

Comment: @barak mano: What do you mean? The purpose of `assertion` is obvious from the above macro definition.

Comment: Yes, but it seems completely unrelated to the purpose of suppressing compiler warnings that you've mentioned in your answer. Why were these two arguments "joined" in the same macro?

Comment: Well,  I don't get any compiler warning after removing that static_cast too.

Answer (score 1):

`static_cast<void>(param);` will evaluate the `param` and discard the result.

If you don't add the cast to `void`:

1. you may get warnings saying you are ignoring the result of
   expression.
2. Even if you pass some illegal code (for example a statement instead of expression) as argument, compiler will accept it happily.

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast)

> 4) If new_type is the type void (possibly cv-qualified), static_cast
>   discards the value of expression after evaluating it.

Comment: And what is the `assertion` for? (the macro takes two arguments).

Comment: @barakmanos Possibly `ASSERT_VALID_PARAM(++validCountDebug, sizeof(int) >= 4)`